# device tree interrupt remapping for pcie and pci device

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, dts, device-tree, pci-e

How to assign interrupt number in device tree for each pcie and pci devices connected to main host bridge via pcie switch and pcie-pci bridge ? Is it require to do it manually or it will automatically assigned ?

Comment: It depends on PIR as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `PCI` or `PCI-E` devices connected via `PCI` or `PCI-E` bus, it is not required to declare each and every node in the device tree. The devices which are not connected to the `PCI`/`PCI-E` bus, need to be declared.

Comment: The devices which are not connected to the PCI/PCI-E bus, need to be declared. Can you please explain this line ?